# Lenovo Trim Yellow rectangular power adapter

Tags: voltage

Need Lenovo Yellow Power adapter connector information, its a MYSTERY to me!! 
Options
‎

Hello all, I recently just purchased my first Lenovo products with the new Yellow rectangular power adapter.

I have the Lenovo M900 Tiny desktop and the Lenovo 23 inch 10dqd monitor. Each have the Lenovo rectangular Yellow Power conectors.
I I am trying to understand how these connectors can be installed in either direction and still have the correct  polarity.

Here are  information that I have researched so far on the internet regading these style connectors.

1. The Lenovo power connectors are called "TRIM Series connecotrs some manufacturers label the connector C36.
2. The connector interior  has two copper plates on each small side of the rectangular connector and a CENTER pin that some manufacturers have labeld the DATA connetion.
3. The Yellow connector at the end of the Power adapter is supplying 20VDC and the current rating of the adapter is proportional to the device it is connected . Ratings usually are in power 35W, 65W , and a 135Watt,

I hope someone can explain how the Power adapter connector can be inserted in either direction , and still supply the correct polarity to the Leveno product?

Thanks Rob

Answer (score 10):

## Quick explanation

This image seems to point to the internal plates being connected internally, with the outside as a 0v line

[image: link]

## In depth explanation

As the two plates are connected, which plate is on which side shouldn't matter, as they are directly connected to each other.

This can best be explained with the following diagram:[image: Lenovo diagram]

Black is 0v, red is 20v, blue is the data pin, if you flip the diagram 180 degrees it is the same:[image: Lenovo diagram]

So no matter which way up the connector is, the inside plates are at 20v, the outside shell is at 0v, making the connector still work, so the laptop can take its power between either of the inside plates and the shell and always get 20v with the same polarity.

## Side note - Data pin

The resistance between the data pin and ground indicates the power rating.

```
|45 W |120 Ω | 
|65 W |280 Ω | 
|90 W |550 Ω | 
|135W |1 kΩ. | 
|170W |1.9 kΩ|
```

[Source](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Power_Connector#slim_tip)

Comment: How exactly is this answer explaining why one can rotate the plug? Seems like the image says it shouldn't.

Comment: The image seems to point to both plates being at 20v, with the outside of the connector at 0v, as the - lines stop at the shell, not the plates

Comment: This is the basic question your "answer" doesn't answer: "I am trying to understand how these connectors can be installed in either direction and still have the correct polarity."

Comment: Added text to explain answer: As the two plates are connected, which plate is on which side shouldn't matter, as they are directly connected to each other

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no electrical background, and therefor I do not understand your answer. Could you edit it further to elaborate more? Explain in basic english why this works? Probably needs some explaination of the interior of the laptop too, not just the connector.

Comment: Sorry, my answer seems to skip over some key points, I will draw some diagrams to make it more understandable

Comment: I have added to the explanation, if it doesn't cover parts well please say and I will fix them

Comment: What will happen if data pin is shorted to 20v?

Comment: I've never tried it (if anyone has it would be interesting to know), I'd assume that the laptop would assume the charger is bad and either refuse to charge or charge at the slowest rate possible