# Lenovo power adapter data pin and + pin sorted

Tags: power-supply, lenovo-laptop

Please refer to [this question](https://superuser.com/a/1246834/960240)

I have same rectangular charging port in my lenovo laptop. For long time it was loosened..

One day I inserted a tiny copper wire inside the connector so that 20v pin can be properly connected. It did work for a while.

However I fear that I have sorted data pin and +20v inner surface. Since then laptop is not starting.

Due to Corona Virus Lockdown, I can't go out for repair also.

Please help me understand how can I check whether I actually shorted out data pin and +20v by mistake.

Or if it did happen what will happen when data pin and + pin are sorted.

Also if someone can explain the role of data pin in the power plug.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The only method to verify if the data and +20v pins are shorted would be to use a multimeter.  Difficult to know how your laptop will behave without a schematic.

Comment: It's not permanently sorted. While charging i inserted a copper wire and it was displaced from its place ... When I removed the charger i saw that it was probable connecting data pin and inner surface of charging connector....

Comment: Does this break down my pc? Or charger?